# Challenging list comprehension question in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am trying to make a nested list like that with list comprehension:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I coded something like:

```
take 3 [take 3 [i .. ] | i <- [1 ..]]
```

but it gives this:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
```

How can I make it like the upper one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
let n = 4 in take n [take n [(i * n + 1) .. ] | i <- [0 .. ]]
```

Which gives

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
```

Using list comprehension **only** you can do this

```
let n = 4 in [[((i - 1) * n + 1) .. (i * n)] | i <- [1 .. n]]
```

Answer (score 7):

The syntax `[1,4 ..]` gives you an infinite list 1,4,7 (and so on). Once you've realized that bit of syntax exists then this becomes much simpler!

`take 3 [ [x,x+1,x+2] | x <- [1,4 ..] ]`

Should give

`[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

Answer (score 2):

You may generalize to `n` items like

```
chunksOf :: Int -> [[Int]]
chunksOf n = take n [[(i-n+1)..i] | i <- [1..], i `mod` n == 0]

Prelude> chunksOf 3
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Prelude> chunksOf 4
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
Prelude> chunksOf 6
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18],[19,20,21,22,23,24],[25,26,27,28,29,30],[31,32,33,34,35,36]]
```